# how to copy .php file from server if I know the full path of that file?

Tags: php

I searched a lot on this and I founded [How to copy file](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#83955), and then I started on it

I write code on my `localhost` the code is from above link and that is:

```
<?php
if(!@copy('http://someserver.com/abc.jpg','./abc.jpg'))
{
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
?>
```

and I used above code and image with url (**http://someserver.com/abc.jpg**) of the site `abc.jpg` is downloaded in my localhost's projects directory... 
So now I tried for **xyz.php** file on same server and I got the `xyz.php` but that file is **empty** so why this happens ? anyone have idea how to download that file, or it is not possible

[image]

Comment: Instead of suppressing errors with `@`, you should read the error message to get a hint why things aren't working.

Comment: ya! using code I displayed in description I downloaded the jpg file and that's correct I got that file as  it is but that code is not working with php file

Comment: What does the PHP-file output if you open it in your browser?

Comment: what does the php file outputs(the one you trie to download) to the browser, because when you download a php file the way you try, it will be parsed through php

Comment: The file actually downloaded in my localhost directory but size is 0 , see above image...

Comment: but the file goes through the php parser before you get it, so if the php file doesn't output anything the file size will be 0

Comment: It outputs nothing I just stored 2 variables in it

Comment: You can't download the php-source like that. That would be the biggest security whole _ever_... like others have said, the web server will parse the PHP and send you the parsed and rendered result...

Comment: If I add output code to that file then it will download ??

Comment: then it will download the output, but not the source, if you want the source you should use something like ftp

Comment: If you enter the URL in a web browser.. what you see in your browser is what you will get...

Comment: Ok ok got it but why the file xyz.php generated with file size 0kb

Comment: because the output is empty, so you get a file without content

Comment: Ok thanx @furrie for your help